Rails mail: delivery_method_options ignored when sending with deliver_later
I am sending email using delivery_method_options so that I can send different emails via different servers. This works fine if I am using deliver_now, but if I use deliver_later, the extra server options are not saved in the delayed_job collection.
Is that expected? Is there a way to send delayed mail using different options for different mailers?
I'm using delayed_job_mongoid if that makes any difference (I don't think it does).
Trimmed-down code:
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_mail(to, subject)
    mail(
      to: to,
      subject: subject,
      delivery_method_options: {
        address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      },
    )
  end
end

NotificationMailer.send_mail('matt@somewhere.com', 'Hi!').deliver_later

This works when using deliver_now, but when using deliver_later, the delivery_method_options is not saved anywhere, it seems to be thrown away.
